# Improving performance of LINQ query with IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm using `IEqualityComparer` to match "near duplicates" in a database using LINQ to Entities.

With a record set of around 40,000, this query is taking around 15 seconds to complete and I wondered if there were any structural changes that could be made to the code below.

**My public method**

```
public List<LeadGridViewModel> AllHighlightingDuplicates(int company)
        {

            var results = AllLeads(company)
                  .GroupBy(c => c, new CompanyNameIgnoringSpaces())
                  .Select(g => new LeadGridViewModel
                  {
                      LeadId = g.First().LeadId,
                      Qty = g.Count(),
                      CompanyName = g.Key.CompanyName
                  }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Qty).ToList();

            return results;

        }
```

**Private method to grab the leads**

```
private char[] delimiters = new[] { ' ', '-', '*', '&', '!' };
private IEnumerable<LeadGridViewModel> AllLeads(int company)
        {
            var items = (from t1 in db.Leads
                          where
                              t1.Company_ID == company
                          select new LeadGridViewModel
                          {
                              LeadId = t1.Lead_ID,
                              CompanyName = t1.Company_Name,
                          }).ToList();


            foreach (var x in items)
                x.CompanyNameStripped = string.Join("", (x.CompanyName ?? String.Empty).Split(delimiters));

            return items;
        }
```

**My IEqualityComparer**

```
 public class CompanyNameIgnoringSpaces : IEqualityComparer<LeadGridViewModel>
    {
        public bool Equals(LeadGridViewModel x, LeadGridViewModel y)
        {
            var delimiters = new[] {' ', '-', '*', '&', '!'};
            return delimiters.Aggregate(x.CompanyName ?? String.Empty, (c1, c2) => c1.Replace(c2, '\0')) 
                == delimiters.Aggregate(y.CompanyName ?? String.Empty, (c1, c2) => c1.Replace(c2, '\0'));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(LeadGridViewModel obj)
        {
            var delimiters = new[] {' ', '-', '*', '&', '!'};
            return delimiters.Aggregate(obj.CompanyName ?? String.Empty, (c1, c2) => c1.Replace(c2, '\0')).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd make the delimiters array static readonly, but I doubt this is much of a performance improvement.

Comment: Yeah, you really should be doing as much of this as possible on the DB end, not all in memory.  That will end up being *much* quicker in all likelihood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to create a computed column on the DB that is the company name with the unwanted characters strippoed out.

Then use this column to do your filtering on.

This will probably ever so slightly decrease performance on inserts, but should hugely improve the query time.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Would you recommend making a function for this?

Comment: Yes, here is the kind of thing that could be adapted... http://davidbridge.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/sql-server-alltrim/

Comment: No problem, please let me know what performance improvement you get.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform all your replacements in one go using [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx):

```
public class CompanyNameIgnoringSpaces : IEqualityComparer<LeadGridViewModel>
{
    static Regex replacer = new Regex("[ -*&!]");
    public bool Equals(LeadGridViewModel x, LeadGridViewModel y)
    {
        return replacer.Replace(x.CompanyName, "")
            == replacer.Replace(y.CompanyName, "");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(LeadGridViewModel obj)
    {
        return replacer.Replace(obj.CompanyName, "").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

That *might* be faster; give it a try! (Also note I've skipped the null checks, you'll probably want to put them back somehow.)

Comment: This can be (very) slightly improved by compiling the regex (using `RegexOptions.Compiled`)